# Python development in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I've been writing and using short Python scripts (~100 lines) for various tasks in Ubuntu using the Geany text editor, which I like for it's simplicity (setup, F5 to run, etc.) and syntax highlighting.

I would like to know if there is a similar application for Windows. Because what I've found so far requires downloading 3 different applications or using a big IDE like eclipse.

Comment: Try IDLE - the default editor that comes with Python.

Comment: really pycharm is very nice ... but there are lots of great options unfortunately SO is not the right place for this question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Geany build for Windows](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Geany to run Python in windows.
But if you need to debug, auto-complete and beautiful IDE, I suggest that you head for [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Python Tools for Windows now works as a plugin for Visual Studio Express (and not just the paid version of Visual Studio) so you get nice free solution that has everything you need with a pretty simple install.  It can be found at:  http://pytools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Any good programmer's text editor will do. I personally use SublimeText 3, but I've used Eclipse + PyDev before to great success, and the usual suspects (emacs, vim, Notepad++) will work just fine too.